# retrieving the values of the pivotItems that were set to true?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I recorded  this macro below.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date")

    .PivotItems("3/15/2020").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("3/17/2020").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("3/18/2020").Visible = True
    .PivotItems("3/20/2020").Visible = True
End With
```

Is there a way to get the values of the pivotItems that were set to true? I would like to place them in an array to manipulate my worksheet.

Comment: What values? If you mean what you have in the with then it's hard coded, nothing really to "get". I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use the VisibleItems property of the PivotField object to get a collection of visible pivotitems...

```
Dim visiblePivotItems As PivotItems
Set visiblePivotItems = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date").VisibleItems
```

Then, you can loop through the collection as follows...

```
Dim currentPivotItem As PivotItem

For Each currentPivotItem In visiblePivotItems
    Debug.Print currentPivotItem.Caption
Next currentPivotItem
```

Alternatively, you can iterate through the collection using the Item property...

```
Dim i As Long

With visiblePivotItems
    For i = 1 To .Count
        Debug.Print .Item(i).Caption
    Next i
End With
```